# JQuery make select box visible on page load based on selected value of a different select box

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am pulling data from mysql and populating a form for edit.

Select box #1 has a value based on what it returned from Mysql.

There are 4 other select boxes.  Each one should become visible based on the value of select box #1.  I have this working fine when the value is changed using the jquery .change().

I want this to work when the page is loaded.

For example:

Select #1 = 13
Select #2 should be visible

Select #1 == 25
Select #3 should be visible

Select #1 == 9
Select #4 should be visible

Select #1 == 26
Select #5 should be visible

else

all should be hidden

Here is my jQuery:

```
       <script>
    var foulTypes = $('#foulTypes');
    var select = this.value;

    //alert the value of Selectbox #1
    alert($('#foulTypes').val());
    if ($('#foulTypes').val() == '13') {
        $('#catDPI').show();
    }

    foulTypes.change(function () {
    //We first disable all, so we dont submit data for more than 1 category
        $("#catDPI, #catOPI, #catOH,  #catDH").hide().find("#category").attr("disabled", true);
    var $divSelectedCategory;
        if ($(this).val() == '13') {
                $divSelectedCategory = $("#catDPI"); 
            $('#catDPI').show();
        } else {
            $('#catDPI').hide();
        }

        if ($(this).val() == '51') {
            $('#catOPI').show();
            $divSelectedCategory = $("#catOPI"); 
        } else {
            $('#catOPI').hide();
        }

        if( $(this).val() == "50"){
            $divSelectedCategory = $("#catOH"); 
            $('#catOH').show();
        } else {
            $('#catOH').hide();
        }

        if( $(this).val() == "9"){
            $divSelectedCategory = $("#catDH"); 
            $('#catDH').show();
        } else {
            $('#catDH').hide();
        }
        //We now enable only for the selected category        
            $divSelectedCategory.show().find("#category").attr("disabled", false).val('');
    }); 
       </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this then

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/svYGW/13/)
change the value of the first checkbox in the top left part and then run the code again

```
<body>
    <input type="checkbox" value="25" id="sel1" checked="checked" />
    <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" value="2" id="sel2" data-trigger="13" />
    <input type="checkbox" value="3" id="sel3" data-trigger="25" />
    <input type="checkbox" value="4" id="sel4" data-trigger="9" />
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="sel5" data-trigger="26" />
    <br/>
    <input type="button" onclick="initCheckboxes();" value="update" />
</body>


window.initCheckboxes = function () {
    var val   = $("#sel1").prop("value"), 
        check = $("[data-trigger="+val+"]");
    $("[data-trigger]").hide();//hide all others
    //and show relevant

    if ( $("#sel1").prop("checked") ) {
        check.prop("checked", "checked");
        check.show();
    } else {
        $("[data-trigger]").prop("checked", false);
    }
}
$(document).ready(initCheckboxes);
```

Comment: This will not work for me.  Select #1 will always have something selected. One of the other select boxes will become visible based on the value of Select #1.  If the values do not match none of the other select boxes should be visible.

Comment: These are Select Menus not checkboxes.  I guess I shouldn't have said boxes.